# grep surrounding characters of a match

Tags: text-processing, grep, string

I'm looking to do a find and replace within a giant database dump, and it's not doing what I think should happen. I'd like to grep for my target string in the file, and then see the surrounding 8 characters or so (I might need to adjust that number, depending). How can I do that?

The reason I can't eyeball this is because there are many hundreds, if not thousands of matches. I want to get some number of characters surrounding the string, and then pipe it into `uniq` or something to see why my find and replace is having unexpected behaviors.

Also, there can be multiple matches on the same line!

Comment: It is not a text file?

Comment: It is, but even just the matches are too big a file to eyeball.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The crude way using `grep` would be something like

```
grep -o "....yourtext...." /path/to/the/dump.sql
```

The number of dots corresponds to the number of characters before/after the grepped text. The `-o` option makes `grep` output only the matches, not the whole lines.

To use `uniq` on the output, remember you have to sort the output first. So typically, you'd do

```
grep . . . | sort | uniq
```

If you are interested in the hitcount for each match, you can get nice output using

```
grep . . . | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Comment: Crude? Utterly sophisticated!

Comment: You could expand on this a little by using the repeat operator: `grep -o '.\{8\}yourtext.\{8\}'`. This is a little less dizzying than counting 8 dots.

Comment: :) By crude I mean you don't play with things like counting matched characters (using ranges) or narrowing the character sets.

Comment: @Caleb and user394: This is exactly what I intended not to suggest (and thus called my method "crude"). One does not need to remember the repeat operator construct, besides - it is even faster to type "....." than ".\{6\}".

Answer (score 8):

Starting from the answer of @rozcietrzewiacz, I can expand to

```
pattern="string"
num=8
grep -on ".\{0,$num\}$pattern.\{0,$num\}" input-file
```

Comment: The "crude" dot sequence is looking better and better all the time :)

Comment: @Caleb: generally the "crude" answer is a good start, but sometimes one want to elaborate a little bit on it.

Comment: The  dot sequence method won't find left or right justified target patterns; this method will. (+1)

Comment: PS.. I just noticed that it won't catch multiples instances of pattern on the same line (as the OP mentioned) when the scope of the trailing 'exta' text of the first pattern overlaps the scope of the leading 'extra' text of the next pattern

Comment: @fred: yeah, `-o` gives only the first match when two matches overlap: `echo 'aaabbbccc' | grep -o 'bb`

Comment: Just a comment, and the same applies to rozcietrzewiacz's answer, too.. I actually meant `aaabbccbbddd` when scanning for 3 characters on either side.. Both `bb` instances are valid and independent, but *only* the first will be reported, because to grep, the pattern it was given *is* being overlapped, but that isn't the patten of interest to the caller... I'll have a fresh go at it in sed (probably tomorrow), but that darn greedy regex upsets things.. and I'm not at all perl savvy...